# How to set the session variables with the eval values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, eval

I have the following link:

```xml
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10px">
<ItemTemplate>
<a id="btnShowPopup5" runat="server" class="thickbox" href='<%#"PopUpPage.aspx?TCode="+Eval("TaskCode")+"&TransSerial="+Eval("TransSerial")+"&TransYear="+Eval("TransYear")+"&mainCode="+Eval("MainCode")+"&year="+Eval("Year")+"&MCode="+Eval("MainCode")+"&DYear="+Eval("Year")+"&PageNew="+Eval("PageNew")+"&ValuesKey="+Eval("ValuesKey")+"&MailNumber="+Eval("MailNumber")+"&candidate_flag="+Eval("candidate_flag")+"&AR=2"+"&TBiframe=true&height=530&width=750"%>'
<asp:Image ID="Image23" runat="server" ToolTip="Back" ImageUrl="Images/cross.png" /></a>
```

I want to set each `eval` value in session variable in `aspx`,instead of passing the variables like that in the query string .

Just for some reasons i can't set those sessions in the .cs so I have to set the sessions in the aspx with the `Eval` values and the `href` should be like this :

---

```
href='<%#"PopUpPage.aspx?TBiframe=true&height=530&width=750"%>'
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your session variable in .aspx page. Something like

```
 <%# Session["Session_TaskCode"] = DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TaskCode") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do same at ItemDataBound event

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label id="lblURL" runat="server" Text="Your Query string comes here"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and find this Label control on ItemDataBound event

```
protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
    //Set your session here
    Label lblURL = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblURL");
    Session["Session_TaskCode"] = lblURL.Text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue will be solved by jquery

Your redirect control

```
  <a id="btnShowPopup5" runat="server" class="thickbox" onClientClick="page_gridview(<%#Eval("TaskCode")%>)" href='Your Redirect URL'/>
```

Put this script in aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function page_gridview(id) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../test.aspx/assignpage",
                data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                    // AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                }

            });

            return false;
        };
  </script>

Put this following method in test.aspx.cs

[WebMethod()]
public static bool assignpage(string id)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] = id;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to show example with session variable.

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["PopUpPage"] = "PopUpPage.aspx?TBiframe=true&height=530&width=750";
}
```

**aspx**

```
<a href='<%= Session["PopUpPage"].ToString() %>'>Testing</a>
```